# build postgresql datasource in wildfly swarm

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, wildfly-swarm

I want to use [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) in [wildfly-swarm](/questions/tagged/wildfly-swarm) via datasource declaration. My problem is the error message `NamingNotFoundException`. The lookup from the `InitialContext` throws this error.

**My project-defaults.yml** (under src/main/resources/project-defaults.yml):

```
 swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
        ExampleDS:
          driver-name: pgsql
          connection-url: jdbc:postgresql://testdb
          user-name: sa
          password: sa
          jta: true
          use-java-context: true
          min-pool-size: 8
    jdbc-drivers:
      pgsql:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        xa-datasource-class-name: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
        driver-module-name: org.postgresql
```

My class for working with the datasources:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.postgresql.Driver;

@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldEndpoint
{
    private final String str_db_source = "java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS";

    @GET
    public String sayHello()
    {
        String str_ret = "hello Dockerworld from swarm";
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Starte DB Insert");
            dowork();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {        Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }  
        return str_ret;
    }

    private void dowork() throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
 Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        InitialContext ctx_PrgSql = null;
        java.sql.Connection pcon = null;
        try
        {
            ctx_PrgSql = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds_PrgSql = (DataSource) ctx_PrgSql.lookup(java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS);
            if (ds_PrgSql == null)
            {            Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Keine Datasource");
            }
            pcon = ds_PrgSql.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pgps;
            //sql insert + params
            pgps.execute();
            pgps.close();
        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {               Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.close_Context(ctx_PrgSql);
            this.close_Connection(pcon);
        }
        System.out.println("DB Insert beendet");
    }

    /**
     * schließt Context
     *
     * @param ctx_obj
     */
    private void close_Context(Context ctx_obj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ctx_obj != null)
            {
                ctx_obj.close();
            }
        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {          Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * schließt Connection
     *
     * @param con_obj
     */
    private void close_Connection(Connection con_obj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (con_obj != null)
            {
                con_obj.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {                Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.wildfly-swarm-docker</groupId>
    <artifactId>dock-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <version.wildfly.swarm>1.0.0.Final</version.wildfly.swarm>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.postgresql>42.2.2</version.postgresql>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>helloworld</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>project-default.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${version.postgresql}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I work with the documentation from http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.4.1/

the entire errormessage:

```
2018-04-17 10:46:51,263 SEVERE [HelloWorldEndpoint] (default task-1) null: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: datasources/ExampleDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:237)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at HelloWorldEndpoint.dowork(HelloWorldEndpoint.java:62)
at HelloWorldEndpoint.sayHello(HelloWorldEndpoint.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.swarm.generated.FaviconErrorHandler.handleRequest(FaviconErrorHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Maven dependency on the PostgreSQL JDBC driver (which you do), WildFly Swarm will define a JDBC driver automatically, so you don't have to do that manually. The driver name will be `postgresql`, as you can find here: http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.4.1/#_autodetectable_drivers

Then, to declare the datasource, this is perfectly enough (copy from http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.4.1/#_example_datasource_definitions):

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      MyDS:
        driver-name: postgresql
        connection-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresdb
        user-name: admin
        password: admin
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker
        validate-on-match: true
        background-validation: false
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter
```

I know this works, and is easier than what you're doing. But what you're doing should work too, so could you paste the entire error message you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks to renaming the above URLs don't work any longer. Now https://docs.thorntail.io/2018.4.1/#_autodetectable_drivers and https://docs.thorntail.io/2018.4.1/#_example_datasource_definitions